# My sql Query returning null inspite of having data in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query which I am building in my DAO Class after taking the input from te users.Its basic a search functionality with around 10 options users provide..I wrote the below query,

1. Users give the range of date.
2. Users provide range of rent.(This part is when it goes as null,I get 0 records.How do I handle null values and still make mysql return data.)
3. Users select an option to see records which has images.
4. Status flag for this query should be 1.
5. Its search by Title.Which means that 1 to 4 points above should be met and keyword given by user should search the column title with like operator.
6. Finally results are sorted by date.

.

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
from `database`.`table` 
WHERE (Date(ctimestamp) BETWEEN '2011-12-02' and '2012-12-06') and (crent BETWEEN '' and '') 
   and (cimg1 IS NOT NULL or cimg2 IS NOT NULL or cimg3 IS NOT NULL or cimg4 IS NOT NULL or cimg5 IS NOT NULL or cimg6 IS NOT NULL or cimg7 IS NOT NULL or cimg8 IS NOT NULL)
   and cflag = 1 and ctitle LIKE '%Testing%' 
order  by Date(ctimestamp) desc Limit 0, 100
```

All the parameters are coming from front end.Now for this query I have close to 13 records with same parameters and conditions,but some how when I run it mysql client it gives me 0 records written.

This query gives me the data correctly,

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
from `database`.`table`
WHERE (Date(ctimestamp) BETWEEN '2011-12-02' and '2012-12-06') 
   and (cimg1 IS NOT NULL or cimg2 IS NOT NULL or cimg3 IS NOT NULL or cimg4 IS NOT NULL or cimg5 IS NOT NULL or cimg6 IS NOT NULL or cimg7 IS NOT NULL or cimg8 IS NOT NULL)
   and cflag = 1 and ctitle LIKE '%Testing%' 
order  by Date(ctimestamp) desc Limit 0, 100
```

The difference between the two is this part

```
and (crent BETWEEN '' and '')
```

Now my doubt is how do I handle this situation when users plans to skip these fields.Appreciate some insights.

Comment: Which server-side language are you using?

Comment: Its servlets,velocity,jsp and jstl.

Answer (score 1):

crent is likely a numeric value. You're asking whether it's between two text fields. That condition will never be true.

Comment: exactly...in SQL, the use of apostrophes `'` are for strings, i.e when you want `WHERE value = 2` you don't need apostrophes. `where value = 'red and blue'` you need apostrophes because it's a string.

Comment: Can you elaborate more , its int column so values are numeric.Its ranges and we need to pull all data which meets those range.

Comment: But still when I remove Apostrophes ,how do I handle null values between ranges.

Comment: use 0 and and 2147483647 for the boundaries

Comment: thanks so when user plans to skip this ,min range I can set is as 0 and max range I can set it up as 2147483647.Maybe I can so the same for date field as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add validation of the input parameters in your program. Do not put it in the sql when it's NULL.

Comment: Its a kind of challenge, consider this, I have fields where in to and from date is required and then range of values max and min for rent,so if user chooses to provide these values,this should work fine,but if he does not provide this, then you mean to say skip those parts in query and return all the data.This will defeat the purpose search functionality.Any other workarounds.

Comment: Ah Crystal you mean to say have Query A when we have all parameters and Query B when some parameters missing ?